# Akka-Http Rest service performance against .NET Web API implementation

Tags: akka, akka-http

So we have a REST API hosted in our environment that is implemented in `.NET Web API`.
I am currently working on a PoC to implement some parts of it in `Akka Http` to showcase some of the performance benefits we get out of the reactive paradigm as opposed to the current WEB API installation.

I already have implemented a short POC with a couple of interfaces and some database integration(CRUD) as well.

I am trying to figure out what things should i showcase in order to clearly show the difference in performance.

Is it correct to say that Akka HTTP does a actor per request handling as opposed to the thread per request approach of traditional frameworks like ASP.NET Web API or Spring ?

Update :

This is what my server code looks like,

```
implicit val blockingDispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-blocking-
dispatcher")
    val agentRoute1 = get {
        pathPrefix("agentStream" / Segment) {
          applicationName =>

            val futuredataListbyStream: Future[Try[Source[Any,NotUsed]]] = Future {
                                 DatabaseProcedure.getDataAsStream(paramName)                                                                                             
}
             onComplete(futuredataListbyStream) {
                                                       case Success(triedResultsSet) =>
                                                         triedResultsSet match{
                                                           case Success(srcStream) =>  
                                                             srcStream.map(x => System.out.println(x.asInstanceOf[String]))

                                                             complete(StatusCodes.OK, "Gotten the data . Return is " + srcStream)
                                                           case Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong here in the rseultset" + ex.getMessage)
                                                         }
                                                         case Failure(ex)    => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong in procedure execution" + ex.getMessage)
        }
       }
      }
```

The database call code looks like this ,

```
def getdataAsStream(paramName: String):Try[Source[Any,NotUsed]] = {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin()
    System.out.println("In blocking db call"+paramName)

    val query: StoredProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("procedure_name")
      .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, classOf[String],
        ParameterMode.IN)
      .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, classOf[String],
        ParameterMode.IN)
      .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, classOf[Class[_]],
        ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
      .setParameter(1,"test")
      .setParameter(2,paramName)

    entityManager.close()


    return Try {
      query.execute
      val list = query.getResultList.asScala.toList
      Source.apply(list)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum performance I have found a few "tricks" are necessary:

1. Chunk Sizes: If you are using `HttpEntity.Chunked` as your `ResponseEntity` in an `HttpResponse` then tune the size of the chunks.  Too many small chunks can degrade performance.  If you know the response entity will always be relatively small then you may want to default to using `Strict` response entity.
2. Async Boundaries:  If your operations for servicing an incoming request won't benefit much from multiple actors, e.g. a lot of IO waiting, then you may want to stick with 1 async boundary instead of multiple.  So use `Flow[HttpRequest].map(...).map(...)` instead of `Flow[HttpRequest].via(Flow...).via(Flow...)`.

Answering your question on Actors per request:

If you use 1 async boundary per my suggestion then yes you would be using ~1 actor per request as opposed to 1 thread.

Answering your question on showcasing:

I think one of the best parts of using akka as a web service is that if you use reactive streams all the way through then the memory usage per request & per connection can remain constant.  So if you are using streams to get the data out of your database integration then a client query which returns an infinite number of rows will only consume a constant amount of memory in your service over time.  This is useful to efficiently utilize your memory per request.

It is always possible to tweak web frameworks so that one is more performant over another, but it is very difficult outside of reactive streams to allow your client to send **any** request they want without worrying about an out of memory exception.

Comment: I am using Akka Http . Basically i am creating routes using the `route` directives. Inside that i am invoking a procedure on a oracle xe instance using JPA. Considering that what would you advise ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya If you're still at the POC phase I would suggest transitioning from JPA to slick, in particular the streaming slick interface as your source for the `HttpEntity` in the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Actually there is a slight issue. Slick's oracle connector is paid and i am looking for a free tool. So when using database mapping i use Squeryl, for executing procedures i use JPA. This is because most of our logic resides as database procedures and we have to call them for our operations.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya I'm not too familiar with the JPA interface, but if it is possible to get something like a ResultSet back, then you can convert the result set into a `Iterator` of rows and use that as the `Source` for your `HttpEntity`.  In general, the lower down that you can get into reactive stream world the better...

Comment: Yeah i do get a Try[List[_]] as a return from my JPA methods .Can you point me to a link to see how i can do that ?  Again thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya You are welcome.  Given a `List[_]` you would just use  `Source.apply` which takes an `Iterable`.  You can then use  `.map` on that Source to convert whatever type is being returned in the List into a `ChunkStreamPart`.  This Source will then be your `ResponseEntity` which goes into the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Yes i am trying out the stuff. Facing some issues with the code where i create the `ChunkStreamPart` . Wanted to share some code snippets with you. Can we have a short chat please. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya sure

Comment: I have added some code snippets to show what i am doing. Basically i am setting up a route using the route directives and calling a database procedure on a different dispatcher since the call is blocking. Now at the end of the procedure run i am returning it as a source to the server. Now i am not sure what to do after this ?

Comment: I need a help on a new question. Can you please take a look ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681847/cannot-configure-the-akka-http-server-when-using-the-akka-http-spring-boot-libra