# Cannot configure the Akka Http server when using the akka-http-spring-boot library

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to setup a project that runs REST services on top of a AKKA HTTP server yet managed by Spring boot.
Now i found this project on gihub as a reference and am using that as libraries to achieve my goal.

This is the project : https://github.com/scalaspring/akka-http-spring-boot

Now i cannot figure out a way to override the actor settings like adding a new dispatcher etc . I also cannot override the default port number to intercept the requests. I intend to handle the blocking requests on a different dispatcher with a thread pool. I understand i need to create a `application.conf` to make it work.
I have created a src/main.resources folder that has `application.conf` but it is are not being read.
Can some one guide me with this ?

My application.conf looks like this,

```
my-blocking-dispatcher {
  # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
  type = Dispatcher

  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"

  # Configuration for the fork join pool
  thread-pool-executor {
     fixed-pool-size = 16
  }

  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 100
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project (or a small project that demonstrates the issue)? How do you verify whether your `/src/main/resources/application.conf` is not being read?